# How to remove class and add another class jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to remove the existing class of my element every time I click the image.

This is my HTML:

```
  <img id="Iphone" src="Image/Technology/Iphone.png" class="technologyImage"/>
  <img id="Android" src="Image/Technology/Android.png" class="technologyImage"/>
```

and this is my javascript:

```
 $(".technologyImage").click(function () {
    $(this).removeClass();
    $(this).addClass("technologySelected");
    $(".technologyImage").css("opacity", "0.4");
    $(".technologyImage").css("filter", "alpha(opacity=40)");
});


$(".technologySelected").click(function () {
    alert("IMAGE IS ALREADY SELECTED");
});
```

I want to alert the user, if the user click the selected image. The code is not working, everytime I click the image it also go to the `$(".technologyImage")` not on the `$(".technologySelected")`.

Comment: You should read about how DOM selection and event binding work. You're binding a `click` handler to the elements that have that class at the time the `.click()` method is invoked. It doesn't automatically update as the classes update.

Comment: This is a good start to http://learn.jquery.com/

Comment: Are you still having this problem? I am using removeClass with jQM 1.4.3 and `removeClass` is not working every time...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you reset the opacity on selected images as well.

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"> 

    $( document ).ready( function() {
        $(".technologyImage").click( function(){
            if($(this).hasClass( "technologySelected")){
                alert("IMAGE IS ALREADY SELECTED");
            }else{
                $(".technologySelected")
                    .removeClass("technologySelected");                
                $(".technologyImage")
                    .css("opacity", "0.4")
                    .css("filter", "alpha(opacity=40)");
               $(this)
                    .addClass("technologySelected")
                    .css("opacity", "1.0")
                    .css("filter", "alpha(opacity=100)");
            }
        });
    });
</script>

</head>
<body>

  <img id="Iphone" src="ios.jpg" class="technologyImage"/>
  <img id="Android" src="android.jpg" class="technologyImage"/>


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$(".technologyImage").click(function () {
        $(this).addClass("technologySelected");
        $(".technologyImage").css("opacity", "0.4");
        $(".technologyImage").css("filter", "alpha(opacity=40)");
        $(this).removeClass(".technologyImage");
  });
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
    $('div.technologyImage').click(function(){

    if($(this).hasClass('technologyImage')){
        $(this).addClass('technologySelected');
        $(this).css("opacity", "0.4");
        $(this).css("filter", "alpha(opacity=40)");
        $(this).removeClass('technologyImage');
    }
    else {
       alert("IMAGE IS ALREADY SELECTED");
    }

});
```

**[DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/jg4ze/1/)**

Answer (score 0):

Please check the code below.

JQuery :

```
$(".technologyImage").click(function () {
   var self= $(this);   
     if(self.hasClass("selected")){
        alert("IMAGE IS ALREADY SELECTED");
     } else {
        if($(".selected").length > 0)
          $(".selected").removeClass("selected");
        self.addClass("selected");
     }
   $(".technologyImage").addClass("opacityHalf");
```

});

Css :

```
 .technologyImage.opacityHalf {
    opacity:0.4;
    filter:alpha(opacity=40);
  }
  .technologyImage.opacityHalf.selected {
    opacity:1;
    filter:alpha(opacity=100);
  }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/r9Yj5/